When was "to list" meaning "to wish" lost?
The meaning of to wish of the verb to list is completely lost today. It survives only in biblical verses of the KJV variant such as:


The wind bloweth where it listeth, and thou hearest the sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh, and whither it goeth: so is every one that is born of the Spirit. (Jn. 3:8 KJV)
Behold also the ships, which though they be so great, and are driven of fierce winds, yet are they turned about with a very small helm, whithersoever the governor listeth. (Jas. 3:4 KJV)


Etymonline does record this outdated usage:

to be pleased, desire" (intransitive), a sense now archaic, mid-12c., lusten, listen "to please, desire," from Old English lystan "to please, cause pleasure or desire, provoke longing," from Proto-Germanic *lustjan (source also of Old Saxon lustian, Dutch lusten "to like, fancy," Old High German lusten, German lüsten, Old Norse lysta "desire, wish, have a fancy"), from *lustuz-, from PIE root *las- "to be eager, wanton, or unruly".

It looks like it has the same root as lust which is mainly used today with animate agents, unless you use it figuratively in personification.
Was there a shift at one point from list to lust? When did that happen and did list simply disappear from the series of synonyms expressing desire, or was it replaced by another verb?

I'd have thought it was to list = to lean [towards] = to favour / prefer. But I haven't investigated (yet! :)

And of course, @FumbleFingers, we also have the expression be inclined to VP and the noun inclination, both of which involve a  metaphor involving preference. But I suspect that this metaphor is to be understood more literally, as in the way one might lean forward to be able to reach and grasp something desirable.

Not to mention as is his bent = as is his inclination. Many idiomatic / metaphoric usages gain / retain currency at least in part through fortuitous chance similarities that rarely get a mention in formal etymologies.

There's also the fairly famous verse "Whoso List to Hunt" by Sir Thomas Wyatt (a bit older than the KJV so it doesn't postdate it any).

The OED has citations up to the 19th century, although it now labels this meaning (list v1) as "archaic". One common construction is in a subordinate clause with "as thee list", "what him list", meaning as you like/want, (he shall do) what he likes, etc. We have Robert Bridges in 1885 from Eros & Psyche:

Thy mortal life is but a brittle vase, But as thee list with wine or tears 'tis filled.

It's also used intransitively in a main clause up to 1869, E. A. Freeman, History of Norman Conquest

The invaders landed and harried where they listed.

In later centuries, it's probably reasonable to regard forms like "as you lust", "where they lust", etc, as fixed formulations, often used for an archaic poetic effect by the 19th century. I don't imagine it's used in everyday speech, or in other formulations (Not "I list some chips!")
In etymology it is from Old English lystan. The lack of written evidence of early Germanic languages makes it hard to trace back further but it is closely related to German lusten, which is also cognate of lust, and the OED says it's not always clear whether which word is intended, with confusion going both ways:

It is often somewhat uncertain whether forms in lust- should be referred to this verb or to lust v.; in southern and perhaps in West Midland Middle English the vowel may represent either u or ü, and the examples are here placed under the one verb or the other as the sense suggests. In other dialects of Middle English, and occasionally in the 16th cent., lust occurs in the sense of list, and with its peculiar inflection (e.g. 3rd singular present lust), and in these cases it is more convenient to regard it as an altered form of this verb, due to the influence of the noun or verb lust, than as a special use of the latter.


Amazing. I did not think that investigating lust more thoroughly would lead me to the archaic usage of list. So we probably lose sight of "list" around the 19th century...
